# Multiline math environment that allows for individually tagged equations grouped by brace as rhs

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, empheq, tags

I'm looking for a math environment that would allow me to write two lines/equations, that needn't be aligned per se, but in which one of the lines looks like this: `a = {a(x)`, where `a(x)` is a system of two equations that would get individual tags denoting the domain of each functional form of `a(x)`.

The following MWE produces the look I'm going for, without the tags.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Some text to show vertical spacing.
\begin{align*}
    &a = \left\{
            \begin{aligned}
                b x - x^3 \\
                0 
            \end{aligned}
         \right. \\
    &\text{where } b = \frac{d^2}{e}.
\end{align*}
Some more text to show vertical spacing.
\end{document}
```

I tried different packages, such as `empheq`, but nothing quite seems capable to produce what I'm looking for. I've come up with a few ways to get something that looks *almost* right, one being a `minipage` of width equal to the `\linewidth` and containing a `centering` command. The other is very similar, but consists of defining a new environment (from an answer to another question here):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newenvironment{mycenter}
    {\parskip=0pt\par\centering}
    {\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}
\begin{document}
Some text to show vertical spacing.
\begin{mycenter}
    \begin{empheq}[left={a=\empheqlbrace}]{alignat*=1}
    &b x - x^3 \tag{$x \leq 0$} \\[1em]
    &0 \tag{$x > 0$}
    \end{empheq}
    where $b = \dfrac{d^2}{e}.$
\end{mycenter}
Some more text to show vertical spacing.
\end{document}
```

The problem with this solution (and the `minipage` one), apart from the fact that it feels forced, is that the vertical spacing at the bottom is too small. Presumably this is due to the fact that I'm using `\dfrac` in the bottom line, but this is non-negotiable. I will not have an ugly in-line fraction there.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `cases` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    Some text to show vertical spacing.
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    &a = \begin{cases}
        b x - x^3 & x \leq 0 \\
        0 & x > 0,
    \end{cases} \\
    &\text{where } b = \frac{d^2}{e}.
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
    Some more text to show vertical spacing.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's not quite what I'm looking for, but if there's really no way of getting that I guess this is the next best thing.